# ngx-cookie-consent message translation with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, cookies, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I'm working on my project and basically want to implement multilang webapp. I'm using `ngx-translate` for that. Now I've faced an issue when trying to implement cookie bar using `ngx-cookie-consent`.
I've got 2 languages: `en|ru` and when I'm clicking the button to change the language - the whole app is translated except the cookiebar. Maybe you've faced such an issue, please give some hints how you managed it.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code how I'm loading the translation message into cookie-consent:

```
this.translateService
  .get(['FOOTER.COOKIES'])
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.ccService.getConfig().content = this.ccService.getConfig().content || {} ;
    // Override default messages with the translated ones
    this.ccService.getConfig().content.message = data['FOOTER.COOKIES'];
    this.ccService.destroy();//remove previous cookie bar (with default messages)
    this.ccService.init(this.ccService.getConfig()); // update config with translated messages
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of only configuring the cookie consent once when you first load the application (at least that's what seems is happening in your code), you can subscribe when the language changes and configure it every time that happens:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
      this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
        this.configureCookieConsent();
      });
    
      this.configureCookieConsent();
    }
    
    configureCookieConsent() {
      this.translateService
            .get(['FOOTER.COOKIES'])
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.ccService.getConfig().content = this.ccService.getConfig().content || {} ;
                // Override default messages with the translated ones
                this.ccService.getConfig().content.message = data['FOOTER.COOKIES'];
                this.ccService.destroy();//remove previous cookie bar (with default messages)
                this.ccService.init(this.ccService.getConfig()); // update config with translated messages
            });
        }
    }
}
```

*I used a component as an example, but of course it should go wherever you currently configure your cookie consent*

Comment: I've tried that thing. Cookie bar re-initializes but the language remains the same

Comment: somehow I've run ng serve again and it worked. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i'm using angular-l10n for translation, So i was making mistake populating a new consent while translating it. The thing is While working with ngx-cookie consent whenever you initialize a consent it will add up to the screen so you will need to destroy the current one just before you initialize new one (make sure there's a consent to destroy or it will throw an error as far as i know):

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.translationOnChangeSubscription = this.translation
          .onChange()
          .subscribe({
            next: (data) => {
              this.ccService.destroy();
              this.setCookieConsentBanner();
            },
          });
      }

      setCookieConsentBanner(): void {
        this.ccService.init({
          content: {
            message: this.translation.translate('COOKIE_CONSENT_MESSAGE'),
            deny: this.translation.translate('DECLINE_COOKIE'),
            allow: this.translation.translate('ALLOW_COOKIE'),
            learnMore: this.translation.translate('ALLOW_COOKIE'),
            link: this.translation.translate('LEARN_MORE_COOKIE'),
            href: 'https://your-privacy-policy-url',
          },
        });
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.translationOnChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.ccService.destroy();
      }
```